# Apply two filters on same column

Tags: python, pandas, filter

```
data = [ 23, 50, 32, 21, 24, 20, 68, 52, 41, 44, 29, 70, 33, 56, 72]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['age'])
```

Trying to filter column to rows with ages equal to, or between ranges(`mask` and `mask1`)

Using a single range returns part of what I need...

```
mask = (df['age'] >= 30) & (df['age'] <=40)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

However, when I try to combine it with another filter no data is returned...

```
mask1 = (df['age'] >= 50) & (df['age'] <=60)
df = df.loc[mask & mask1]
```

I have also tried:

```
df = df.loc[mask or mask1]
```

However, this produces the following error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How can I combine the two filters?

Comment: ```df = df.loc[mask | mask1]``` should work

Comment: `or` does not work with Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to use `mask | mask1` (bitwise **or**)? It is normal that no data is returned as you both select age below 40 and above 50, which is incompatible.

```
>>> df.loc[mask | mask1]
    age
1    50
2    32
7    52
12   33
13   56
```

Comment: @Sujay I wanted to provide the example with OR, which I think is what OP wants. In the end doesn't make a big difference

Comment: Appreciated. `mask | mask1` worked but the word `OR` didn't

Comment: @DiopChopra OR was not a operator, just an English word ;) I rephrased for clarity